# Absolute URL in java

Tags: java, url, object, request, absolute-path

I am trying to get absolute URL in java class, but getting an error even after type casting it to Object.

Any suggestions

```
   String file = ((Object) request).getRequestURI();
     if (((Object) request).getQueryString() != null) {
        file += '?' + ((Object) request).getQueryString();
     }
     URL reconstructedURL = new URL(request.getScheme(),
                                    request.getServerName(),
                                    request.getServerPort(),
                                    file);
     System.out.println(URL.toString());
```

Comment: What is the actual type of `request`? By default, request is already an `Object` (no need to cast), and it most certainly does not contain a `getRequestURI` method. I presume you're getting a method not found error. Is request supposed to be an HttpServletRequest? http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Comment: @Daniel: Yes it should be HttpServletRequest.

Answer (score 4):

Addition to what @Daniel said [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class has not static method like `.toString()`. You should use `reconstructedURL` instead

I don't test it but please try this

```
String file = (request).getRequestURI();
if ((request).getQueryString() != null) {
    file += '?' + (request).getQueryString();
}

URL reconstructedURL = new URL(request.getScheme(),
                               request.getServerName(),
                               request.getServerPort(),
                               file);
System.out.println(reconstructedURL.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

A cast to Object is never nessecary, because everything is an object. I suggest posting the stacktrace of your error.

`((Object) request).getRequestURI()` doesn't work, because Object does not have a `getRequestURI()` function. Just leave the cast away.